# Expo app crashing on android, runs fine on web

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have an app built with Expo. Runs fine on web, but crashes on android.

The error message informs me its something to do with 'path' and 'rect' being undefined, and that components should start with capital letters. The offending part of the code is some svgs that I am importing like so,

`import Logo from './assets/logo.svg'; <Logo width={120} height={40} />;`

as per expo docs.

The full error message is

`invariant violation: view config getter callback for component` path`must be a function (received`undefined`). make sure to start component names with a capital letter.`

It is a standard app built with `npx create-expo-app my-app-etc`

No other configurations have been made, other than installing node modules etc

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To display SVG you need npm library

```
npm i react-native-svg
```

for more, you can check this article https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-react-native-tutorial-with-examples/